# Jersey - welcome message when user hits API URL

Tags: java, rest, jersey

Consider I have a rest API like this:

```
@Path("/TestAPI")
public class APIMapper {
   @GET
   @Path("/hello")
   public String sayHello() {
       return "Hello";
   }
}
```

Basically user can hit URL like this: `http://localhost/app/TestAPI/hello` and they would get response as "Hello" but if they hit URL like this: `http://localhost/app/TestAPI` they generally get blank screen/response as output
We want that if user just give URL like this `http://localhost/app/TestAPI` without giving any specific api, instead of giving blank response, we want to output something like `Welcome to API, below list of services available`(slightly similar to .NET webservices where if we hit URL, it displays "Following operations available"). Is there a way I can do same thing using Java/Jersey? Can anyone please help me?

Comment: @peeskillet yes it is plain text (at-least for this, remaining all others are json)

Comment: Were you looking for some kind of response that is auto-generated?

Comment: Yes slightly like that, in-case if user doesn't hit specific API we should give him a default message.

Comment: Maybe look into using something like [Swagger](http://swagger.io/) for documentation. You can redirect to that documentation. Otherwise, for something more simple, can't you just create the response yourself?

Comment: You could also make use of [Exception Mapping](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/representations.html#d0e5207) to map any Not Founds

Comment: Yes I want to very simple response, I am getting confuse how to write response for toplevel element like `/TestAPI` this. @peeskillet

Comment: Just don't add a `@Path`, or use `@Path("/")`. But you can only have one HTTP method for each method

Comment: @peeskillet thank you :) That made  the trick.